# Dart: Initialize enum from JavaScript var

Tags: enums, environment-variables, constants, dart, dart2js

In my HTML file I have:

```html
<script>
    var serverName = "dev.myapp.com:8080";
</script>
```

Then, in my Dart code:

```dart
import "dart:js" as js;

String SERVER_NAME = js.context["serverName"];
String SIGNIN_PLACE_URL = "http://$SERVER_NAME/signin";
String SIGNOUT_PLACE_URL = "http://$SERVER_NAME/signout";

class Place {
    static const SigninPlace = const Place._(SIGNIN_PLACE_FRAGMENT_URL);
    static const SignoutPlace = const Place._(SIGNOUT_PLACE_FRAGMENT_URL);

    static get values => [SigninPlace, SignoutPlace];

    final String fragmentURL;

    const Place._(this.fragmentURL);
}
```

I'm getting an error inside my "enum" in regard to both my `fragmentURL` arguments for both values:

> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

So it looks like I need to make these `fragmentURL`s `const`, but not sure how. What's the solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `SERVER_NAME` is unknown at compile time it can't be a constant.
If you want `SigninPlace`/`SignoutPlace` to be a constant `SERVER_NAME` must be a constant too.

A possible workaround

```dart
class Place {
  static String SERVER_NAME;

  static final SigninPlace = const Place._("signin");
  static final SignoutPlace = const Place._("signout");

  static get values => [SigninPlace, SignoutPlace];

  String get fragmentURL {
    Map places = {
                  "signin": "http://${SERVER_NAME}/signin",
                  "signout" : "http://${SERVER_NAME}/signout" };
    return places[_fragmentURL];
  }
  final String _fragmentURL;

  const Place._(this._fragmentURL);
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  Place.SERVER_NAME = "aServer";
  print(Place.SigninPlace.fragmentURL);
}
```

If you move the Strings containing the interpolation into a function (here a getter) the interpolation is deferred until the value is requested. At this time your `SERVER_NAME` should already be assigned.
You could add an exception or different error handling if `fragmentURL` is requested before `SERVER_NAME` is set.

Comment: I was searching for a workaround like [using Can I apply Dart's string interpolation dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886796) but couldn't yet find one.