# Twirl view engine look alike

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, functional-programming, dart

I am working with Dart and I want to implement my own view engine since as I know, Dart hasn't anything like that. I used Twirl in Scala with the Play2 Framework and I want to know how it is done. I mean. That way of create "html" files with functions of scala... and you can use the @ character to use scala code blended in the plain html and so on...

Is this thing possible in Dart? I know Dart has some functional programming basis.

Thank you.

Comment: Polymer and Angular and probably others are using such technology. They have their own parser to translate expressions within the HTML to Dart code using a transformer at build time. There are also server side template packages at pub.dartlang.org but I haven't used any of them myself yet. Using this from the other side is using Darts string interpolation.

Comment: I did try to use string interpolation with a loaded HTML file but it doesn't work. It shows like ${mything.name} for example. I am interested in a server-side view engine btw.

Comment: If it didn't work it was probably becsuse of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886828/217408

Comment: Thank you very much. Think this is what I needed. Can you post an answer to vote it? I will leave a link when my library is ready for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in Dart is to use string interpolation

```dart
String s = 'world';
print('Hello $s (${s.length})');
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't work with passed around strings. If you need to pass it around, wrap it in a function like

```dart
String template(String arg) => 
  print('Hello $arg (${arg.length})');
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886828/217408 for more details.

There are also some server side template engines available for Dart

- [Mustache](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache)
- [Mustache No Mirror](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache_no_mirror)
- [Mustache4Dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache4dart)

bit I haven't used any of them myself yet.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying but think you have an error. You though the var name was "world" and it is "s". so, it is print('Hello $s (${s.length})'); Just saying.