# Dart string interpolation reading a file

Tags: dart

I know that you can use the string interpolation to reference an object within a string literal but, is this possible with a string given from reading a text file?

I mean. Something like:

```
Function MyTemplate() {
    return (Context context) {
        return readMyFile(); // String: "My name is ${context.name}"
    }
}
```

I have read
[Can I apply Dart's string interpolation dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886796/can-i-apply-darts-string-interpolation-dynamically)

But this seems to work only with hardcoded strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation only works with hardcoded strings. You need to build your own solution or use one of the existing template packages.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using the [splitMapJoin](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/splitMapJoin.html)  method in the core library:

```dart
String inter(String format, Map<String, dynamic> sub ,{String placeholder = ""}){
    return format.splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'{.*?}'),
    onMatch:    (m) => sub[m.group(0).substring(1, m.group(0).length - 1)].toString() ?? placeholder,
    onNonMatch: (n) => n);
}
```

There is also a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/interpolation) to handle this.

However, these solutions are not satisfactory for my application, which also needs to interpolate a string from a file, provided by users. Since less assumptions can be made in this scenario, it is desirable that error can be detected from the input string. Thus, I developed [another package](https://pub.dev/packages/interpolator) to achieve this, with slight performance enhancement. This package is still in a primary stage, but all functionalities are tested. Please feedback if you have any suggestions.