# Flutter replace varable after string is build

Tags: string, flutter, dart, replace

I am trying to replace variable in a string which is dynamically generated within a loop

```
String url = "";

data.forEach((key, value) {
      url = "$url&$value=\${$key}";
});
```

Above method return something like this "https://example.com/test.php?user=${id}&pass=${pass}"

I have two variable named id and pass. But after I generate this string dynamically it doesn't replaces the variable when I print it.

```
var id = 1;
var pass = abc;

String url = "";

data.forEach((key, value) {
      url = "$url&$value=\${$key}";
});

print(url);
```

It should return "https://example.com/test.php?user=1&pass=abc"

Comment: Instead of ``url = "$url&$value=\${$key}";`` do ``url = "$url&$value=$key";`` or ``url = "${url}&${value}=${key}";``

Comment: maybe because variable u r printing is  'URL' instead of 'url'?

Comment: not working it just prints like this &pass=pass

Comment: URL was the writing mistake I fixed that but still the same issue

Comment: add your ``data`` object

Comment: depending what widget are you performing this action in you should perform a setState({}) https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

this way your interface will be updated with the new values.

Comment: my data variable is just an array like {id:user, pass:pass}

Comment: "https://example.com/test.php?user=${id}&pass=${pass}" works if i print it directly but not if I build the URL with the loop dynamically. Main problem is this

Comment: the way I told should be working. You might be doing something wrong. Post your complete code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template file evaluation in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326641/template-file-evaluation-in-flutter). Dart string interpolation is compile-time syntactic sugar; you cannot dynamically generate the template string.

Comment: Its the complete code. I already told you that string is building correctly via loop but variables are not replacing. If I print the same string generate by loop in next line it works

Comment: anyone? not ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62326641/), string interpolation in Dart is compile-time syntactic sugar.  As briefly mentioned in [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour), string interpolation is performed on string *literals*.  It is not performed on general `String` objects.

You will have to devise another approach to do what you want.  For example:

```dart
String url = "";

data.forEach((key, value) {
  if (key == "\${id}") {
     key = id;
  } else if (key == "\${pass}") {
     key = pass;
  }
  url = "$url&$value=$key";
});
```

or a variation that might be better if you have more variables to deal with:

```dart
var allowedKeys = {
  "\${id}": id,
  "\${pass}": pass,
};

String url = "";

data.forEach((key, value) {
  key = allowedKeys[key] ?? key;
  url = "$url&$value=$key";
});
```

(Incidentally, your use of "key" and "value" seems confusing and backward from typical use.)