# How to execute String Interpolation from a File in dart

Tags: linux, string, file, dart, interpolation

I'm relatively new in dart programming, and I noticed how powerful String Interpolations are.
I was wondering if I could read a file, and the contents would contain Dart Syntax for String Interpolations. But things did'nt go the way I wanted

Here is what I did:

file.txt:

```
${((int i){print(i);})(11)}
```

the Dart Code I wrote:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() async {
  File myfile = File("this.bin");
  var q = await myfile.readAsString();
  print(q);
}
```

But the output was not what I expected:

```
$ dart simple.dart
${
  (
    (int i)
    {
      print(i);
    }
  )
  (11)
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you specified what you did expect.

Comment: @buddemat I was expecting it to print an integer 10, because I have tested it with a string. let's say I have a string: String a = "${((int i){print(i);})(11)}"; and if I write a, it will print 10

Comment: String interpolation is compile-time syntactic sugar, so no, string interpolation won't help you.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29784832/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886796/.