# use random variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just trying to make an application that gives a random text to a user.
but I'm confused and I can't have access to my variables. I can't append my random number to the `text` word.

Here are my variables :

```
    var text1 = 'Of cource do it!';
    var text2 = 'Do it.';
    var text3 = 'why don\'t you do it faster?';
    var text4 = 'I have no idea about it.';
    var text5 = 'it\'s better to don\'t do it.';
    var text6 = 'Don\'t do it.';
    var text7 = 'if I was you , I would not do it.';
    var text8 = 'Never do it.';
```

And here is how I make a random number:

```
    void ran(){
      numm = Random().nextInt(8)+1;
    }
```

This is how I try to append a random number with `text` word:

```
Text('$text$numm',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
```

How can I mix `random number` with `text`?

Comment: Use an array. If you find yourself making variable names like `text1`, `text2`, `text3`, etc. you should be using an array.

Comment: String interpolation is compile-time syntactic sugar, so no, string interpolation won't help you. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29784832 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886796.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> text = [
    'Of cource do it!',
    'Do it.',
    'why don\'t you do it faster?',
    'I have no idea about it.',
    'it\'s better to don\'t do it.',
    'Don\'t do it.',
    'if I was you , I would not do it.',
    'Never do it.'];
      
      int ran() {
        numm = Random().nextInt(8) + 1;
        return numm;
      }
```

then use like this

```
Text(text[ran()],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),))
```

Comment: Just added some tweaks...pls just try now and accept the answer if it helps

Comment: This will throw an error as the variable `text` does not exist. You cannot merge variable name in `Dart`

Comment: i completely forget about the "text" i was only thinking about the random number...then my code is crap!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your texts into a `List`, and fetch the values with `numm`:

```dart
List texts = [text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8];

var numm = Random().nextInt(texts.length);

Text(texts[numm],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
```

Comment: No " texts[numm] " part does not work ...
have you any other opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var text1 = 'Of cource do it!';
var text2 = 'Do it.';
var text3 = 'why don\'t you do it faster?';
var text4 = 'I have no idea about it.';
var text5 = 'it\'s better to don\'t do it.';
var text6 = 'Don\'t do it.';
var text7 = 'if I was you , I would not do it.';
var text8 = 'Never do it.';

List<String> list = [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8];
final rand = Random().nextInt(7);
Text(list[rand], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
```